# List of Kerrigan's Abilities

Tags: starcraft-2

What are Kerrigan's Abilities in the campaign for the new Heart of the Swarm expansion?

- Ability Name:
- (If applicable/available) Energy Cost / Cooldown:
- Description:
- Kerrigan Level Available:

(This would be a good reference to have for other questions asking about specific abilities.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: Spoilers Below!

Tier 1: Level 0

- Kinetic Blast: Kerrigan deals 300 damage to a target unit or structure from long range
- Heroic Fortitude: Kerrigan gains +200 maximum life. Life regeneration rate increased by 100%.
- Leaping Strike: Kerrigan leaps to her target and deals 150 damage to it. Can be used without a target to travel quickly. Kerrigan also gains a passive +10 damage increase, but attack range is reduced by 3.

Tier 2: Level 0

- Crushing Grip: Enemies in target area are stunned for 3 seconds and take 30 damage over time.
- Chain Reaction: Kerrigan’s attacks deal normal damage to her target and then jump to additional nearby enemies. Deals 10 damage to up to four secondary targets.
- Psionic Shift: Kerrigan dashes through enemies dealing 50 damage to any in her path. Overall movement speed is also increased by 30%.

Tier 3: Level 10

- Zergling Reconstitution: Killed Zerglings respawn from your primary Hatchery at no cost. Respawns up to 10 Zerglings every 30 seconds until all Zerglings have returned to life.
- Improved Overlords: Overlords morph instantly and provide 50% more supply.
- Automated Extractors: Extractors automatically extract vespene gas without Drones.

Tier 4: Level 20

- Wild Mutation: Friendly Zerg units in the target area gain +200 maximum life and 100% increased attack speed for 10 seconds. Does not affect heroic units.
- Spawn Banelings: Kerrigan spawns six Banelings with timed life.
- Mend: Heals Kerrigan for 150 life and friendly biological units nearby for 50 life. An additional 50% of the amounted healed regenerates over 15 seconds.

Tier 5: Level 35

- Twin Drones: Drones morph in groups of two at no additional cost, in minerals or supply.
- Malignant Creep: Your units and structures gain increased life regeneration and 30% increased attack speed on creep. Creep Tumors spread creep faster and farther.
- Vespene Efficiency: Vespene gas harvesting efficiency increased by 25%.

Tier 6: Level 50

- Infest Broodlings: Enemies damaged by Kerrigan become infested and spawn two Broodlings with timed life if killed quickly.
- Fury: Each attack temporarily increases Kerrigan’s attack speed by 15%. Can stack up to 75%.
- Ability Efficiency: Kerrigan’s abilities have their cooldown and energy cost reduced by 20%.

Tier 7: Level 60*

- Apocalypse: Deals 300 damage to enemy units and 700 damage to enemy structures in a large area.
- Spawn Leviathan: Summons a mighty flying Leviathan with timed life that deals massive damage to ground and air units and has energy-based abilities.
- Drop-Pods: Delivers 40 Primal Zerglings, 5 Primal Roaches, and 5 Primal Hydralisks with timed life to the battlefield.

*Note that all Tier 1 - 6 active abilities cost 50 mana, and all Tier 7 abilities cost 100 energy and start on a cooldown, meaning you have to wait 5 minutes to use them (or 4 minutes with Ability Efficiency).

[Source](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Sarah_Kerrigan_%28Heart_of_the_Swarm%29)